# Gedit does not auto-highlight .x10 files

Tags: gedit

Since I am working with X10, I got the X10 language highlighting for gedit. This works, but whenever I open an .x10 file I first have to change the "Highlight Mode" to "X10", otherwise there is no highlighting at all. How do I make gedit auto-detect .x10 files?

Answer (score 0):

If X10 files are not highlighted by default you can activate [Snippets](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-snippets.html.en) plugin. I assume you have set the .lang file under `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs`. From plugin you can activate x10 highlightniing by shortcuts or snippet name followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. I am not sure what *Drop target* option is for, nevertheless there is no way make it auto-detect IMHO.

I know this is not what you've been looking for but it will ease the trouble :)

[image]